# Norm of vector with respect to operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define $L$ is a linear operator maps from $E^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, its norm is defined as $||L||_{op}=\sup\limits_{||x||=1}L(x)$, where $||\cdot||$ is any norm on $E^n$.

How to show that $||x||=\sup\limits_{||L||_{op}=1}L(x)$?

Can anyone give me some hints I will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is easy. For the equality, use Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Hi, could you specify how to find a subspace to restrict $||L||_{op}=1$ by using Hahn-Banach? Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is contruct $L$ with $\|L\|=1$ and such that $L(x)=\|x\|$. Do this first on a suitable one-dimensional subspace, and then use HB.